# What does "telling the truth has become a societal antiquity" mean?

Tags: meaning, american-english

What does  "telling the truth has become a societal antiquity" mean?

I saw it on a random post earlier today. I guess it could mean that it's an outdated method: that many people resort to lies.

Comment: Slightly OT: It's impossible to be polite without telling lies or refraining from making truthful observations. This means that telling some types of lie has been approved of (at least implicitly) for as long as society has placed a value on politeness.

Answer (score 4):

The author's argument seems to be that people (in the author's society) formerly told the truth but that now they don't tell the truth - or at minimum, that they now view truth-telling as an unusual and antiquated habit.

The tone is that of curmudgeonly insistence that people acted better in the 'good old days'; as opposed to the morally degenerate society and people of today.

I'll leave it to you to describe the numerous flaws in this argument. ;)